# Can I forcibly deactivate an iPad? If not, what are my options?

Tags: ipad, apple-id, ios

I've just been given a corporate iPad mini that previously was used by someone else in my team. It *appears to have* been factory reset - it is taking me through the welcome and setup process (language selection/wi-fi selection/etc.), but once I've connected it to the network, it says the iPad is currently linked to an **existing** Apple ID (it masks it with stars, but shows enough information that I can see who that is) and asks me to sign in with that Apple ID (which I don't have). The person in question is uncontactable. Is there any way I can forcibly reset it and remove its link to that Apple ID? If not, are there any options which make it more useful than a lightweight doorstop?

Comment: If it still wants a previous ID, it hasn't been reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no. It's a security feature to prevent thieves from selling the device on, as it is rendered useless if you don't have the person in question's apple ID and password.

Comment: Only if it's been put in Lost Mode, otherwise you can simply reset it.

Comment: @Tetsuijin, how would I reset it? I am seeing the welcome/setup process screen, there appears to be no option to do that. If I don't connect it to Wifi or iTunes, it refuses to proceed; when I do, it asks for the Apple ID.

Comment: You can't 'simply' reset it. It defeats the whole point of asking for a password. They wouldn't ask for one if not.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier "it asks for the Apple ID" - do you mean it is telling you an appleid and askign for the password, or does it just want an appleid?  If its the second, go to appleid.apple.com and make a new one.

Comment: @Tyson, an existing one. I clarified the question.

Comment: @StanHutcheon, understood, I was trying to understand what Tetsujin was referring to.

Comment: It wasn't clear initially at what point it was requesting the ID - if it was at the App Store etc, then it hadn't been reset but was still a possibility. If you can't get in at all, it's now a brick.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way to discover if it's possible to reset is to try it…

[image]

If you can't get that far, it's a brick.

Comment: Couldn't find a pic of an iPad, but it's very similar

Comment: I can't get that far. I'm in the welcome/setup process screens.

Comment: This doesn't bypass activation lock. See the linked question and answer...

Comment: then it's a brick. Apple themselves can clear it, if you can prove ownership; there's no other way. Give it back to IT & let them deal with it.