# Once I've signed in with a previous owner's Apple ID, then set up iCloud with my own Apple ID, is the activation lock transferred to me?

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud, apple-id

An iPad I have was previously set up with a different Apple ID (see [my question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/161383/can-i-forcibly-deactivate-an-ipad-if-not-what-are-my-options) and [its duplicate](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock)). I have since obtained the Apple ID and password for the previous owner, and used those to proceed through the welcome/setup process. It then asked for an another Apple ID for iCloud, and I gave it mine. Does that mean that it is now fully 'switched over' to my Apple ID, or might the activation lock still be associated with the previous owner, were the device ever to be reset? There doesn't appear to be anywhere in the settings screen explicitly associated with the activation lock, just the iCloud ID (which according to the setup process is a separate concept).

Comment: Check Settings > iCloud > Find My iPhone to make sure it is now using **your** AppleID instead of the previous owner's. You don't specifically mention this detail.

Comment: @IconDaemon it is using mine, yes. It's not clear to me that the activation lock ID and the iCloud ID are the same thing, though.

Comment: Is FindMyiPhone on the iPad? If not, install it from the appstore.  Log into iCloud.com, can you view the location of the iPad?

Comment: @Tyson, it's on another iPad, and yes I can.

Comment: This question is marked as a duplicate, but it is not. The other question mentions a SIM card, but that's not relevant in this case. The setup process has a two-step questionnaire regarding the iCloud ID, but it's not clear what happens with the iCloud ID you entered *once* you've bypassed the activation lock. That's the nub of the question.

Comment: The answer on the linked question shows a way to find the AppleID a device is associated with for activation lock. If I understand *your* question correctly that's exactly what you want to know. Otherwise please explain.

Comment: The answer to the prior question states "If you are asked for the previous owner’s Apple ID and password, the device is still linked to their account... On iOS 7, the part where you are asked if you want to enter your Apple ID is the step that means it's not locked to another iCloud account." Based on this, your device is still linked to the prior owner's account, and that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's procedure on how to tell if a device is free from activation lock is posted pubicly:

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201365

There are steps you can take on the device, but I prefer the web interface:

https://www.icloud.com/activationlock/

The steps to remove a device from the previous owner is here: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4515

It doesn't look to me like you have completed the steps needed to know it's detached from the lock. I would go over TS4515 and or use the procedure in HT201365 if the web says it's still locked to an Apple ID.